# Convert list of words to array in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

This might be just a simple question, but I'm not very familiar in terms of PHP.

I have here a list of words separated by a < br / > tag, example:

```
<div id="list">
    gmail.com<br />
    yahoo.com<br />
    yahoo.co.jp
</div>
```

And, I want to convert it to a list of values in an array looking like this

```
$acceptedDomains = array('gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.co.jp');
```

How can I achieve this output?

I need this actually for domain email checking and here's how the function works:

```
            $acceptedDomains = array('gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.co.jp');
            $email = $current_user->user_email;

            if(in_array(substr($email, strrpos($email, '@') + 1), $acceptedDomains)) {
                //if user is a member, show form.
                echo $email . " is valid" . "<div>" . CFS()->get('mo_email_list') . "</div>";
            }
```

I want to replace the value of $acceptedDomains to what was listed under the id="list"

Comment: how are you getting the input? where is that div coming from and how are you getting it back to php?

Comment: I used a wordpress plugin called custom field suite where you can input custom textarea field on the admin side. the div is what's wrapped around the output.

The php is something like this:
`<?php echo CFS()->get('mo_email_list'); ?> `

Comment: that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<?php
$input='<div id="list">gmail.com<br />yahoo.com<br />yahoo.co.jp</div>';
$acceptedDomains = explode("<br />", strip_tags($input, "<br>"));
print_r($acceptedDomains);
?>
```

**Output:**

Array ( [0] => gmail.com [1] => yahoo.com [2] => yahoo.co.jp )

Comment: thanks! this is working properly, but how do I make it have an output like this? `$acceptedDomains = array('gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.co.jp');`

Comment: @false-hero You just need to save that exploded value to your variable thats it. Now you can use your variable anywhere you want..... I updated my answer.....

Comment: @false-hero See my updated answer, put that code and let me know if you found any issue.

Comment: @false-hero My pleaser :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$input='<div id="list">
    gmail.com<br />
    yahoo.com<br />
    yahoo.co.jp
</div>';
$newStr=strip_tags($input, '<br>');
$acceptedDomains=explode("<br>",$newStr);
var_dump($acceptedDomains);
?>
```

Above Code will return the output 
as per you want ):

Comment: hey thanks! I saw the output but it was a bit different from what I need. should be something like this `$acceptedDomains = array('gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.co.jp');` since that's how the function accepts input

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
<?php
$input_string = '<div id="list">gmail.com<br />yahoo.com<br />yahoo.co.jp</div>';
$strip_tag_str = strip_tags($input_string, "<br>");
echo "<pre>";
print_r(explode("<br />", $strip_tag_str));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

OUTPUT of Above Code :

```
Array
(
    [0] => gmail.com
    [1] => yahoo.com
    [2] => yahoo.co.jp
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$input='<div id="list">
          gmail.com<br />
          yahoo.com<br />
          yahoo.co.jp
        </div>';
$acceptedDomains=explode("<br />", strip_tags($input, "<br>"));
print_r($acceptedDomains);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
<?php $acceptedDomains = explode("<br />", CFS()->get('mo_email_list')); ?>
```

Or if `<div id="list"></div>` is also a part of `CFS()->get('mo_email_list')` output try:

```
<?php $acceptedDomains = explode("<br />", strip_tags(CFS()->get('mo_email_list'),"<br>")); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
$data = '<div id="list">
    gmail.com<br />
    yahoo.com<br />
    yahoo.co.jp
</div>';

$newdatavar=strip_tags($input, '<br />');
$explodevar=explode("<br />",$newdatavar);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($explodevar);
```